# How can I draw XYZ points and depend point size on the Z value in R?

Tags: r, plot, maps, geospatial

I have data frame where two first columns describes points coordinates (X, Y) while two next columns stores values.

I would like to plot them (on map) as a points, but I wish that point size will depend on value (for example Z1 value).

How can I do that in R?

I know that there's a [rasterFromXYZ](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/rasterFromXYZ) command, but I don't know the counterpart for points.

My sample data are as follows:

```
myData <- structure(list(X = c(20.688, 18.905, 19.086, 21.135, 21.979, 
22.495), Y = c(52.387, 53.747, 52.495, 53.466, 54.093, 52.879
), Z1 = c(1050L, 359L, 424L, 393L, 1478L, 573L), Z2 = c(48L, 
38L, 20L, 150L, 138L, 120L)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z1", "Z2"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggmap` library, you could do something like:

```
# set up the sample dataset
myData <- structure(list(X = c(20.688, 18.905, 19.086, 21.135, 21.979, 
                               22.495), Y = c(52.387, 53.747, 52.495, 53.466, 54.093, 52.879
                               ), Z1 = c(1050L, 359L, 424L, 393L, 1478L, 573L), Z2 = c(48L, 
                                                                                       38L, 20L, 150L, 138L, 120L)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z1", "Z2"
                                                                                       ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

# load the ggmap library
library(ggmap)

# set the part of the world to show
location <- c(lon = mean(myData[, "X"]), lat = mean(myData[, "Y"]))

# choose map type
maptype = "terrain"

# get the map from google (choose zoom you like, or let it choose manually)
map <- get_map(location = location, source = "google",
               maptype = maptype, crop = FALSE, zoom = 6)

# print the map
ggmap(map) +
        # add the points, where X is longitude, Y latitude and size is calculated based on Z1 (you might choose some other scaling of Z1)
        geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y, size = 1+Z1/sum(Z1)), data = myData)
```

Comment: Thanks! Am I able to use plot (from raster package) on the same plot? I need to draw vector file (.shp) that shows country border.

Comment: You can create a raster object and then use inset_raster or inset_ggmap to plot it

Comment: Also, if you want to stick only to `raster` package you can create your map with that package and then use function `points` from the R base graphics to plot points of various sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with most plotting tools, for example with ggplot:

```
ggplot(myData,aes(x=X,y=Y)) +
geom_point(aes(size = sqrt(Z1), alpha = .5))
```